# ggplot how to fix plot area with y axis of different decimal places?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to generate scatter plot with the same plot area(the area where all the dots are in, not the whole picture). Here's the code that I've been using:

```
p = list()
for(i in 8:38){
  name = colnames(allbbb)[i]
  ylabel = bquote(atop(bold(.(name)),log2(FC)))
  xlabel = bquote(atop(bold("DNA Lesions"),log2(FC)))
  corre = paste0("r = ",round(cor(allbbb[,42],allbbb[,i]),digits=2))
  ptemp = ggplot(allbbb,aes(x=allbbb[,42],allbbb[,i])) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.15,size=0.3,shape=19) +
    xlim(quantile(allbbb[,42],0.005), quantile(allbbb[,42],0.995)) + 
    geom_smooth(method="lm") +
    ylim(quantile(allbbb[,i],0.005),quantile(allbbb[,i],0.995)) + 
    theme_bw() +
    annotate(geom="text", x=quantile(allbbb[,42],0.99), y=quantile(allbbb[,i],0.9), 
             label=corre, size=5, fontface="bold") +
    ylab(ylabel) + xlab(xlabel) + 
    theme(axis.text= element_text(size=15),axis.title=element_text(size=20))
  p[[i]] <- ptemp
  #ggsave(paste0(name,"sc.png"))
}

ggarrange(p[[7]],p[[8]],p[[9]],p[[10]],p[[11]],p[[12]],p[[13]],p[[14]],
          p[[15]],p[[16]],p[[17]],p[[18]],p[[19]],p[[20]],p[[21]],p[[22]],
          p[[23]],p[[24]],p[[25]],p[[26]],p[[27]],p[[28]],p[[29]],p[[30]],
          p[[31]],p[[32]],p[[33]],p[[34]],p[[35]],p[[36]],p[[37]],p[[38]], ncol=4,nrow=8)
ggsave("allscatterplot.png",width=18,height=26.4,units="in")
```

However, due to the different # of decimal place in the graph, I noticed that the actual plot areas are slightly different in plots.

Down below is an example:

[image: SS of Plot]

I tried to use function in `scale_y_continuous()` to make everything have same d.p. in the y axis but since I need ylim, it doesn't really work. Could anyone suggest some ways to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ggarrange` is from the `ggpubr` package:

```
ggarrange(plotlist=p[7:38], ncol=4, nrow=8, align="hv")
```

I haven't tested this, as your example is not reproducible. However, `align="hv"` should take care of the panel size issue.

Using the `plotlist` argument reduces the amount of typing needed to specify which plots to include.

Also, for future reference, you don't need to use both `ylim` and `scale_y_continuous`. You can specify limits in `scale_y_continuous` as well (note that you need only one call to `quantile`):

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = quantile(allbbb[,i], c(0.005,0.995))
```